# Error with the ajax and transaction in mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have the ajax is :

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function(){
    $('#addtocart').click(function () {
      var size = $('#ddlsize').val();
      var color = $('#ddlcolor').val();
      var id ='@Model.ProductId';
      alert(size + color +id);
      $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AddTocart", "ShoppingCart")',
        data: {                                             
          id:  id,
          size: size,
          color: color,                                           
        },
        dataType: "html",
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
          alert("Da them vao gio hang");
        },
        error: function () {
          alert("Co loi xay ra vui long thu lai");
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

And in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddTocart(int id, string size, string color)
{
  Product productitem = dbcon.Products.Where(p => p.ProductId == id).SingleOrDefault();
  var cart = ShoppingCart.Getcart(this.HttpContext);
  cart.AddtoCart(productitem, size, color);
  return View();
}
```

without the httpget addtocart.When i click button addtocart,some time error in ajax,but it do the action addtocart and save in database,some time success and some time error but doesnt save database,i dont know what problem happend?

Comment: `return View();` is wrong for an ajax call, you need to use something like `return Json(new { success = true });`

Comment: It alwhays error or some time @markpsmith ,because i have another ajax like this and return view,but  it alsway success,

Comment: What's the error you got?

Comment: @ekad,When i debug,i click button add to cart and this cause error alert("Co loi xay ra vui long thu lai");but it do the action AddTocart and save database,after this it almost success in ajax.And tell me how it always error several time when i call it

Comment: @ekad you can go to http://congle1988-001-site1.myasp.net/Product/Details/3 to see the error,but it still do the funtion addtocart and save database when you try several times

Comment: Can you add the controller code that generates `/Product/Details/3`? I would guess it's `public ActionResult Details(int id)` ?

Comment: yes,this is my controller that generates to details:    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            Product item = dbcon.Products.Where(p => p.ProductId == id).SingleOrDefault();
            return View(item);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of this syntax

```
url: '@Url.Action("AddTocart", "ShoppingCart")'
```

The `url` option of the ajax call would be `/ShoppingCart/AddTocart`, and since you call `return View();` in your controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddTocart(int id, string size, string color)
{
    Product productitem = dbcon.Products.Where(p => p.ProductId == id).SingleOrDefault();
    var cart = ShoppingCart.Getcart(this.HttpContext);
    cart.AddtoCart(productitem, size, color);
    return View();
}
```

You're telling the controller to open this url after inserting to database: `/ShoppingCart/AddTocart`, which I would guess doesn't exist so you get the error because you don't have `/Views/ShoppingCart/AddTocart.cshtml` or you don't have this method without `[HttpPost]` attribute in `ShoppingCartController` class.

```
public ActionResult AddTocart()
{
}
```

You should return json as follows

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddTocart(int id, string size, string color)
{
    Product productitem = dbcon.Products.Where(p => p.ProductId == id).SingleOrDefault();
    var cart = ShoppingCart.Getcart(this.HttpContext);
    cart.AddtoCart(productitem, size, color);
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

and change `dataType` option to `json`

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function(){
    $('#addtocart').click(function () {
      var size = $('#ddlsize').val();
      var color = $('#ddlcolor').val();
      var id ='@Model.ProductId';
      alert(size + color +id);
      $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AddTocart", "ShoppingCart")',
        data: {                                             
          id:  id,
          size: size,
          color: color,                                           
        },
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
          alert("Da them vao gio hang");
        },
        error: function () {
          alert("Co loi xay ra vui long thu lai");
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I can understand a little but it error at the first time i run in localhost,after that it almost success,And ekad if i return a view and i have this view,is this error??

Comment: if you have this view: `/ShoppingCart/AddTocart.cshtml` and you have `public ActionResult AddTocart` method without the `[HttpPost]` attribute in `ShoppingCartController`, then you won't get the error, but it depends on what you want to do after the ajax call is successful, do you really want to redirect to `/ShoppingCart/AddTocart`?