# How to pass selected value of dropdownbox from a mvc view to controller action method?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have drop down box in my view which is filled by the sql database table. in the drop down i have different values, i want to pass the selected value of the dropdown on button click to the controller action method. here is how drop down is populated.

```
public ViewResult ProductDetails(int productId)
        {
            Product product = repository.Products
               .Include(p => p.Reviews)
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
            List<string> available = new List<string>();
            available.AddRange(product.AvailableSizes.Split(',').ToList());
            ViewData["AV"] = new SelectList(available);
            return View(product);
        }
```

and then in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("AV")
```

my controller action method is:

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(Cart cart, int productId, string returnUrl, string size)
        {
            Product product = repository.Products
                        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
            if (product != null)
            {
                cart.AddItem(product, 1,size); //no overload for method 'AddItem' takes 3 argument, Error!
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
        }
```

and finally the cart class is below:

```
public void AddItem (Product product, int quantity)
        {
            CartLine line = lineCollection
                .Where(p => p.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (line == null)
            {
                lineCollection.Add(new CartLine { Product = product, Quantity = quantity  });
            }
            else
            {
                line.Quantity += quantity;
            }
        }
```

i tried [Error with the ajax and transaction in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932369/error-with-the-ajax-and-transaction-in-mvc) but had no luck, any idea?

**Edit for Sir Rion Williams:**
The whole cart class is below for your more information.

```
public class Cart
    {
        private List<CartLine> lineCollection = new List<CartLine>();
        public void AddItem (Product product, int quantity)
        {
            CartLine line = lineCollection
                .Where(p => p.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (line == null)
            {
                lineCollection.Add(new CartLine { Product = product, Quantity = quantity  });
            }
            else
            {
                line.Quantity += quantity;
            }
        }
        public void RemoveLine (Product product)
        {
            lineCollection.RemoveAll(l => l.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID);
        }
        public decimal ComputeTotalValue()
        {
            return lineCollection.Sum(e => e.Product.ProductPrice * e.Quantity);
        }
        public void Clear()
        {
            lineCollection.Clear();
        }
        public IEnumerable<CartLine> Lines
        {
            get { return lineCollection; }
        }
        public class CartLine
        {
            public Product Product { get; set; }
            public int Quantity { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your View contains the following element :

```
@Html.DropDownList("AV")
```

This means that however you are posting this to your server will need to be expecting either an explicit parameter called `AV` or a property on a model that is being bound to named `AV` :

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(Cart cart, int productId, string returnUrl, string size, string AV)
{
     // AV should be populated as long as you are properly serializing
     // the <form> with the "AV" element in it and it should store the
     // selected value
}
```

You can ignore this approach if your `cart` object has a property already named `AV` as MVC will automatically bind it.

**Non-AJAX Example**

For example purposes, if you wanted to submit this value, you could create a `<form>` element that points to your `AddToCart()` action and contains your DropDown :

```
<form action='@Url.Action("AddToCart","YourController")' method='post'>
      @Html.DropDownList("AV")
      <input type='submit' value='Add to Cart' />
</form>
```

when you click the submit button, this would `POST` the values of your `<form>` to the `AddToCart()` action and it would bind the `AV` property to its selected value :

```
// The [HttpPost] decorator allows this to accept POST requests
[HttpPost]
public void AddToCart(string AV)
{
    // You should be able to see your selected value here (example)
    var selected = AV;  
}
```

**AJAX Example**

The AJAX example works very similar to the previous method, but differs in how the `<form>` itself is actually posted. If you are using jQuery, you could wire up an event to capture the `submit` event, ignore it and manually `POST` the contents via AJAX :

```
<form action='@Url.Action("AddToCart","YourController")' method='post'>
      @Html.DropDownList("AV")
      <input type='submit' value='Add to Cart' />
</form> 
<script>
      $(function(){
           $('form').submit(function(e){
                // Ignore any default behavior / submission
                e.preventDefault();
                // Make an AJAX post to your action (short-hand)
                $.post('@Url.Action("AddToCart","YourController")', $(this).serialize(), function(){
                      alert('Your value was posted successfully!');
                });
           });
      });
</script>
```

Additionally, in your `AddItem()` method, I don't see where your `lineCollection` variable is defined and it should be noted that if the `else` clause is executed nothing will really happen :

```
public void AddItem (Product product, int quantity)
{
      // Create an instance of your line
      var line = lineCollection.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID);
      if (line == null)
      {
           // Is lineCollection some global or static variable?
            lineCollection.Add(new CartLine { Product = product, Quantity = quantity  });
      }
      else
      {
           // Since line is actually created (and scoped) to this
           // method, this really isn't going to do anything
           // as line will be disposed of upon exiting this method
           line.Quantity += quantity;
      }
}
```

Comment: Rion thanks for that, but is it possible to make it a bit clear as far as i am quite new to mvc? i don't have a property called AV and neither a parameter what do you advise?

Comment: Well the easiest thing to simply "check" if your value is being posted or not is that you could add a line within your add to cart method to check the `AV` value as follows : `var selected = Request["AV"];`. You can use the debugger to see if that value is being populated properly and then use it as you need. Alternatively, you could use the approach I mentioned earlier of actually adding a parameter to the action called `AV` and MVC would handle binding the value on its own.

Comment: Sir Williams can you please have a look at my question again the parameter 'size' i have passed in my action method shows an error and the error is written in the question. thank you again

Comment: You can see the cart line collection which is a private method, the question is updated accordingly for your more information.

Comment: with suggested method the value is not posted to the controller, i get the value once i click on the button via alert(size) but the value is not posted to the controller shows null, any suggestion?